# Replace characters between string

Tags: python, string, function, replace

I am trying to do a code in Python that I can create a hybrid animal:

> hybridize('goat', 'sheep')
>   'geep', 'shoat'
>   hybridize('crab', 'fish')
>   ('crish', 'fab')

but I don't know how I could change the consonants between these words.

Comment: What is your algorithm? Is is that you want to keep all the first consonants of the first word with all the letters starting with the first vowel of the second word?

Comment: yes, I don't know how I could indicate to slice it.

I did a function first to indicate the vowel, but and then? Should I use if?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using regular expressions: `[aeiou][a-z]+` matches the end of the animal word after the first `n` consecutive consonants. `^((?![aeiou][a-z]+).)+` matches the first `n` consecutive consonants at the beginning of the animal word using negative lookahead.

```
import re

def hybrize(a1, a2):
    ending = "[aeiou][a-z]+"
    s_ = f"{ending}"
    e_ = f"^((?!{ending}).)+"

    a1_s_ = re.sub(s_, "", a1)
    a1_e_ = re.sub(e_, "", a1)
    a2_s_ = re.sub(s_, "", a2)
    a2_e_ = re.sub(e_, "", a2)

    return a1_s_ + a2_e_, a2_s_ + a1_e_

print(hybrize("goat", "sheep"))
print(hybrize("sheep", "goat"))
print(hybrize("crab", "fish"))
print(hybrize("fish", "crab"))
```

**Output:**

```
('geep', 'shoat')  
('shoat', 'geep')  
('crish', 'fab')  
('fab', 'crish')
```